# User without home access remote machine ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, ssh-keys

I want a production server to push backup files to a backup machine. Backups are being done via `www-data` cron script (as they can be edited by website cms), and once it has finished the idea is to send this files to backup server via rsync & ssh. `www-data` is a 'no login user' account (no home, no ~/.ssh folder).

In a 'user can login' account I would login, generate a certificate with `ssh-keygen` and place public key into `.ssh/authorized_keys` in backup machine.

How can I make this 'user no login' account to send files to remote machine with rsync and ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make this 'user no login' account to send files to remote machine with rsync and ssh?

you can try something like the following

```
# su -l www-data -s '/bin/bash' -c 'rsync -rzav --rsh="ssh -p 22 -i user_can_login_private.key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /var/www/html/ user_can_login@{backup_machine_ip}:/backup/html/'
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, as this script is already being ran by www-data user cron, the script would be something like: `cmd="rsync -rzav --rsh='ssh -p ${sshPort} -i ${bkPrivateKeyFile} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ${bkFilePath} user@${backupIp}:/backup/${bkFileName}"`